# Spring Security : Redirect to page by providing rolename from DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I have 3 User ROLE ACCESS, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_USER.(roles may increase in future. so hardcoding role is not at all mandatory)

My security_servlet.xml is something like this

```
 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/candidate*" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUP_ADM')" />

    <form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <!-- <user-service> <user name="rohit" password="rohit" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" 
            /> <user name="ronnie" password="ronnie" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> </user-service> -->

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, active from users where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select us.username, ur.authority from users us, user_roles ur 
    where us.user_id = ur.user_id and us.username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

After Login it redirects to "/". What I want is if role is "ROLE_ADMIN" then it should be landed on admins default page like "/admin/profile", If role is "ROLE_USER" then "/user/profile"

I used default-target-url but its not working for me.

Comment: Write your own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead of using the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Spring MVC controller to redirect user to desired page:

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
            return "redirect:/admin/profile";
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER"))
            return "redirect:/user/profile";
        // and so on
    }

}
```

Comment: As we are comparing Role hardcore like "ROLE_ADMIN", If I create new Role in future then i need to change code and then again compile it viz process will continue. Instead of this is there any other generic approach available?

Comment: @Ronnie You can make it more generic, but you get the idea with getting the roles and doing a redirect.

Comment: Exactly. I can get roles from db or any property file. But I am confused, if user has two roles then where should i suppose to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Update the success handler of the spring security like this

```
<form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied"  authentication-success-handler-ref="roleBasedRedirect"/>
```

Add the `roleBasedRedirect` service bean

Now you can do it like following

```
public class RoleBasedRedirectService extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler{



    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            for(GrantedAuthority authority : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities())
            {
                if(authority.toString().equals("ROLE_ADMIN"))
                    return "/admin/profile/";
                else if(authority.toString().equals("ROLE_USER"))
                    return "/user/profile/";
            }
            return "";
    }

}
```